# RadGrid cannot show Edit Form, because of Exception in DataBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, telerik, telerik-grid

i got a problem.

I am following this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultcs.aspx) to show a Edit Form on RadGrid. But i can't display the Edit Form when i click Edit button.

This is the code i am using:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="radGridTarget" GridLines="None" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"
    AllowAutomaticInserts="True" PageSize="10" Width="500px"
    OnItemDeleted="radGridTarget_ItemDeleted" OnItemInserted="radGridTarget_ItemInserted"
    OnItemUpdated="radGridTarget_ItemUpdated" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowPaging="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    onneeddatasource="radGridTarget_NeedDataSource"
    onitemcommand="radGridTarget_ItemCommand" >
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <NoRecordsTemplate>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="20">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <h2 style="color:Black">No Data Found.</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </NoRecordsTemplate>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"/>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn HeaderStyle-Width="10%"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Sales" HeaderText="NIK Sales" Display="false"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Target" DefaultInsertValue="Target" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" UniqueName="Target" DataField="Target">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Amount" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="Target Amount" SortExpression="Amount" UniqueName="Amount">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Campaign" HeaderText="Campaign" UniqueName="Campaign" HeaderStyle-Width="20%"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="StartDate" UniqueName="StartDate" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="EndDate" UniqueName="EndDate" HeaderStyle-Width="10%"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this target?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" ConfirmTitle="Delete" HeaderText="Delete"
                HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="DeleteColumn">
            </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
        </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
            <FormTemplate>
                <table id="tableFormEdit" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="0" rules="none"
                    style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr class="EditFormHeader">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <b>Target Details</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table id="Table3" width="450px" border="0" class="module">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Target:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="radDropDownTargetList" EmptyMessage="Target" runat="server" SelectedItem='<%# Bind("Target") %>'
                                            DataSource='<%# PopulateTargetList() %>' DataTextField="Desc" DataValueField="Value" Skin="MetroTouch" TabIndex="5" >
                                        </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Amount:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="radTextAmount" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Amount" Text='<%# Bind("Amount") %>' TabIndex="6"
                                            Skin="MetroTouch" ShowButton="false" ShowSpinButtons="false">
                                            <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
                                        </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Campaign:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="radDropDownCampaignList" EmptyMessage="Campaign" runat="server" SelectedItem='<%# Bind("Campaign") %>'
                                            DataTextField="Desc" DataValueField="Value" Skin="MetroTouch" TabIndex="7" >
                                        </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Start Date:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="radStartDate" runat="server" Culture="en-US" TabIndex="8" Skin="MetroTouch">
                                            <Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server">
                                                <SpecialDays>
                                                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-BackColor="Yellow">
                                                    </telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                                                </SpecialDays>
                                            </Calendar>
                                            <DateInput DisplayDateFormat="d/M/yyyy" DateFormat="d/M/yyyy" LabelWidth="40%" TabIndex="6">
                                            </DateInput>
                                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>End Date:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="radEndDate" runat="server" Culture="en-US" TabIndex="9" Skin="MetroTouch">
                                            <Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server">
                                                <SpecialDays>
                                                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-BackColor="Yellow">
                                                    </telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                                                </SpecialDays>
                                            </Calendar>
                                            <DateInput DisplayDateFormat="d/M/yyyy" DateFormat="d/M/yyyy" LabelWidth="40%" TabIndex="6">
                                            </DateInput>
                                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "Insert" : "Update" %>'
                                runat="server" CommandName='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "PerformInsert" : "Update" %>' TabIndex="10"></asp:Button> 
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" TabIndex="11"
                                CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </FormTemplate>
        </EditFormSettings>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true">
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and

```
protected void radGridTarget_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName) //"Add new" button clicked
    {
        GridEditCommandColumn editColumn = (GridEditCommandColumn)radGridTarget.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn");
        editColumn.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.RebindGridCommandName && e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted)
    {
        e.Canceled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        GridEditCommandColumn editColumn = (GridEditCommandColumn)radGridTarget.MasterTableView.GetColumn("EditCommandColumn");
        if (!editColumn.Visible)
            editColumn.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Where part that i gone wrong?
the working part is "Add New Button" only. and when i click edit command, there's nothing to show.

---

**UPDATE**

I am trying to debug using IE, and i got something.
When i click edit, it says:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Specified cast is
>   not valid.

Question:
1. Why the errors happen?

2. How to solve this problem?

Please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using DataSource to bind or using Code behind to bind ?
If using Code Behind please include onNeedDatasource

Comment: This JS error is the way the MS AJAX framework shows you server errors. Step through the server code to see where a the cast goes wrong, probably you need a type check first somewhere.